# Function that creates a file in a directory

Tags: files, directory, functions

I have 4 directories: dir1 dir2 dir3 dir4. I want to create a file in each directory. I know I can do this: touch file1.txt and then move it to dir1, then touch file2.txt then move it to dir2 but it takes ages. How can I create a function that creates a text file in each of the directories? Thanks

Comment: What should the function's inputs be? a list of file names? a list of directories? an integer range with/without strings for the `dir` and `file` prefixes? BTW you don't need to move files after, you can create them in place ex. `touch dir1/file1.txt`

Comment: @steeldriver the function inputs should be file1 or file2 etc. I mean is it possible to create a function that generically creates a text file and puts it in a directory. Then everytime I call the function I specify which file goes in which directory for example file1 in dir1

Comment: In that case I don't see any time saving of using a function over simply typing `touch dir1/file1.txt` and so on

Comment: I see. It was less of a time saving issue more of a "is it possible to create a function like that?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create and then move files - you can `touch` them in place ex.

```
touch dir1/file1.txt dir2/file2.txt dir3/file3.txt
```

It won't really save you any time (or typing) but you can of course create a shell function for this - a minimal implementation would be

```
mkfile() { touch "$1"/"$2"; }
```

which you can invoke as

```
mkfile dir1 file1.txt
```

although of course it should really include some checking / error handling (such as what to do if `$1` is not a directory, or doesn't exist).

If your file and directory structure is always of the form `dirN/fileN.txt` then there are some better ways to automate the creation such as

```
seq 1 3 | xargs -I{} touch dir{}/file{}.txt
```

or even (using GNU `parallel` and brace expansion)

```
parallel touch dir{}/file{}.txt ::: {1..3}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you regard as 'ages'. There's no function that would create 4 files in parallel for you. Assuming you're using bash or similar the 'easiest' way is probably a loop. e.g.:

```bash
DIR=dir
for i in 1 2 3 4
do
  touch "${DIR}i"
done
```

That's pretty quick on any machine I use. If you want an atomic 4 file create, I'm afraid there's no real way to do this.

Note that if there's content in the 4 files, the 'quickest' way in terms of lag between the first file appearing and the last one would be create the files elsewhere and then `mv` them.

Comment: what does ${DIR}i do? Does it take input from user? I can't take input from user in my code unfortunately. Is there a way to put this loop in a function?

Comment: In bash ${DIR} expands the value of the variable DIR (Which was previously set to the text 'dir' on the line above the for statement)

The loop therefore runs 4 times. Performing

   touch dir1
   touch dir2
   touch dir3
   touch dir4

What (scripting?) language are you writing in?